# antiholomorphic derivative on z^a

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, dirac-delta

It is a somewhat well-known statement that $\partial_{\bar z} \frac{ 1 }{ z } \propto \delta^2(z, \bar z)$. I wonder if it there is generalization to $z^\alpha$ with $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$? For $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{-1\}$ the answer should be zero, but I'm not sure about more generic $\alpha$.

Comment: Try cases. Parametrically integrate the line integral for $z^\alpha$ and see what you get. If you are using the principal branch of log, then the bounds are understood to be $(-\pi,\pi)$